# How can I use an icon for clusters in Mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox

I have followed [the example code](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/create-style-clusters/) and been successful in getting clustering working using the `CircleLayer`. However, I would like to be able to change the cluster images to icons. I tried changing the `CircleLayer` to a `SymbolLayer` like this:

```
mapboxMap.addImage(CLUSTER_ICON, clusterBitmap);

SymbolLayer clustered = new SymbolLayer(CLUSTERED_POINTS_LAYER, POINTS_SOURCE);
clustered.setProperties(iconImage(CLUSTER_ICON));

clustered.setFilter(Filter.gt("point_count", 0));
mapboxMap.addLayer(clustered);
```

but had no such luck. Is it possible for me to use an icon instead of a colored circle to represent clusters?

Answer (score -1):

At first you must add Image to MapBox. Like this:

```
mapboxMap.addImage(CLUSTER_ICON, SomeBitmap);
```

Then you can set property to layer. Like this:

```
SymbolLayer clustered = new SymbolLayer(CLUSTERED_POINTS_LAYER, POINTS_SOURCE)
   .withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage(CLUSTER_ICON);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've got. It didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @nt-complete You set icon clustered.setProperties(iconImage(CLUSTER_ICON)); 

It is not correct. 

First you must add this icon to map mapboxMap.addImage